# Design simple ios application using NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7.1, nsurlsession

I am writing my first application objective-c for iOS 7.1. I'm probably something fundamentally do not understand why I have this question arose.

The application is quite simple: the client to communicate with an external service using web api. To send a http-requests I use NSURLSession.
I have a simple architecture.

THETALETestViewController - this view controller. This class uses THETALEAPI.h
THETALEAPI - is the realization of web api. I have highlighted in a separate class, to each external API method has been implemented in one place. Here is the formation of a query for each method. This class uses THETALEHttpHandler.h.
THETALEHttpHandler - this class is directly responsible for sending http-request and receiving http-response.

Here is the code from THETALEHttpHandler.m to send POST - query.

```c
-(void) sendPostToURL:(NSURL *)url withParams: (NSString *) inParams competion:(void     (^) (NSData *data)) completion
{
    NSLog(@"sendPostToURL");

    // _csrftoken a token in cookie
    NSMutableDictionary *cookieProperties = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [cookieProperties setObject:@"csrftoken" forKey:NSHTTPCookieName];
    [cookieProperties setObject:_csrftoken forKey:NSHTTPCookieValue];

    [cookieProperties setObject:[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:2629743] forKey:NSHTTPCookieExpires];

    NSHTTPCookie *cookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:cookieProperties];
    [_httpCookieStorage setCookie:cookie];

    [_sessionConfig setHTTPCookieStorage:_httpCookieStorage];


    // tried and so
    // //   NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil //delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];   
    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:_sessionConfig];


    NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // _csrftoken a token in the parameter
    NSString *params = [@[inParams, _csrftoken] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

    [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
                                                   completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                    NSLog(@"Got response %@ with error %@.\n", response, error);
                                                       if(error == nil)
                                                       {
                                                           NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                                           NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);
                                                       }
                                                   completion(data);
                                                   }];
    [dataTask resume];

}
```

So, block completion is not running in main thread, and asynchronously, so while a request is sent and there is a reception and treatment response - main thread runs on. In principle, it is clear and logical, but I want to "login" using this method, respectively, by clicking on the "Login" I have to go after a successful request and response and processing the user should see the answer. What capabilities iOS achieve such behavior to main thread waiting for the completion of the asynchronous block and displays the appropriate information? Or maybe it is not worth waiting for, and it just somehow need to notify?

Unless, of course, does not make separate classes, and to do everything in viewController, then, assuming that delegates would come up, but I want to make a bit of modularity in its application.

Maybe I'm wrong designed system, then you can explain or show an example of how it is usually done?

I think that this requirement is rather banal and the answer is somewhere nearby, please explain, thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry. Translated the comments in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) for the API calls.[Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial) explaining in details how to use it the right way.Also you can use [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to notify the view controller when the call is successful/fail

Comment: I've thought about Notification and delegirovanii.To there I will need to do inside block notification to view controller?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understood your question

Comment: I'm interested in implementation. Within the specified architecture how would you do notification?

Comment: post notification when the api call is finished (it should be infide the block):[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: @"some name to identify the notification" object: nil userInfo:nil];
and always remove the observer : [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"same notification name" object:nil];
register the view controller to 'listen' for the notification :[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self                                 selector:@selector(methodToHandleTheNotification) name:@"same notification name" object:nil];

Comment: Thanks! It's usefull. I will try this method. Please tell me the architecture for this application is correct?

Comment: Accept the answer if it is what you needed

Comment: This is really what I need. I would like to hear more options. This will be possible if I accept?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can execute a block on the main thread using `dispatch_sync`. But that's not really the problem here. You're trying to do too much in one block of code.

Your flow needs to look something like this:

1. Have you recorded a username/password?
2. If not, ask for one
3. Run your network request
4. Error handling would include looking for invalid credentials, in which case the request would be cancelled and your code would jump to step 2.

Comment: Why do you think that I want in one block to do too much? I just want to accept the response and give it further in THETALEAPI.
I tried to use 'code' dispatch_sync 'code', but the program did not wait for the block execution. My question actually is how to implement what you have described in the list.

Comment: @njc The paragraph of text underneath your code suggests that you want to ask the user to login _during_ the network request, i.e., the network request should wait until the information has been obtained from the user before continuing. That's not how it needs to work. You need to obtain the credentials and then perform the request.

Comment: Probably that I incorrectly explained. Already have credentials, the user enters them. Now I want to wait for an answer, and depending on the answer to show information to the user interface.

Comment: So the problem is just that the completion block doesn't run on the main thread?

Comment: My problem was that I did not know how to tell me about the interface that the response is processed, but I suggested above. I will use or delegation or notification. Is that correct?